# Dynamically creating counters

Tags: counters

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{order}
\newcounter{version}
\counterwithin{version}{order}

\renewcommand{\theorder}{\arabic{order}}
\renewcommand{\theversion}{\alph{version}}
\newcommand{\rom}[1]{\textbf{\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral #1\relax}}}

\newcommand{\entry}[4]{%
  \rom{#1}%
  \if #2i\stepcounter{order}\fi%
  \theorder{}/%
  \if #3i\stepcounter{version}\theversion\fi%
  \if #4t/od\fi%
}

\begin{document}

\entry{1}{i}{i}{t}

\entry{1}{0}{i}{t}

\entry{2}{i}{i}{0}
%\textbf{II}1/a

\entry{2}{i}{0}{0}
%\textbf{II}2

\entry{2}{i}{0}{t}
%\textbf{II}3/od

\entry{1}{i}{i}{0}
%\textbf{I}2/a

\entry{2}{i}{0}{t}
%\textbf{II}4/od

\end{document}
```

which generates the PDF:

[image: current output]

How can I modify it in order to associate a unique counter to each of the different first arguments of `\entry`. The desired output would be:

[image: desired output]

Comment: I can’t understand the logic of **II**2/a. Shouldn’t it be **II**1/a? Can you explain what’s the rule?

Comment: Hey egreg, you are right. I wrote this very late at night, instead of II2/a I want of course II1/a. I will correct the question in a moment

Comment: Can the third argument be different from `i`? And, in that case, what should be done?

Comment: @egreg I have edited the question, hopefully it is more clear now. The third argument corresponds to a counter within, that sometimes is not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still not sure about the logic, but this reproduces the desired output.

For each main label (first argument), I define two counters, the second one relative to the first one.

When the second or third argument is `i`, the related counter is stepped and printed; if it's `0`, no stepping is done and only the first counter's value is printed.

Finally the trailing “/od” is printed if the fourth argument is `t`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\entry}[4]{%
  \ifcsname c@entry@#1\endcsname
  \else
    \newcounter{entry@#1}%
    \newcounter{entry@#1@sub}[entry@#1]%
  \fi
  % print the label
  \textbf{\@Roman{#1}}%
  % check the second argument
  \if #2i%
    % step the counter
    \stepcounter{entry@#1}%
  \fi
  \arabic{entry@#1}%
  % check the third argument
  \if #3i%
    \stepcounter{entry@#1@sub}%
    /\alph{entry@#1@sub}%
  \fi
  % check the fourth argument
  \if #4t%
    /od%
  \fi
}

\makeatother  

\begin{document}

\entry{1}{i}{i}{t} (\textbf{I}1/a/od)

\entry{1}{0}{i}{t} (\textbf{I}1/b/od)

\entry{2}{i}{i}{0} (\textbf{II}1/a)

\entry{2}{i}{0}{0} (\textbf{II}2)

\entry{2}{i}{0}{t} (\textbf{II}3/od)

\entry{1}{i}{i}{0} (\textbf{I}2/a)

\entry{2}{i}{0}{t} (\textbf{II}4/od)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly it. Small question, does the @ symbol have a special meaning in the counter name `entry@#1@sub`? Could I have used another name, like simply `sub#1`? I assume yes, because of the `\makeatletter`.

Comment: @rpanades I used it just as a separator.